# Set niceness value in a systemd user service

Tags: linux, xorg, systemd, user, nice

I'd like to start xcape with a nice value of -20 as non-root. However setting a nice value of -20 requires root permissions. So I was wondering whether this is somehow possible.
I also tried to create a system service and setting `User=myuser`, but xcape requires xorg and thus `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`

What I got so far:

```
[Unit]
Description=xcape: esc on caps lock
PartOf=graphical-session.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Nice=-20
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xcape -t 180 -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape'

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: did you manage to set it?

Comment: I came up with a workaround, I posted it as an answer. I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually came up with a workaround using sudo<sup>1</sup> as systemd doesn't support this out of the box afaik.

### 1) Add command to sudoers file

First add the following line to the end of `/etc/sudoers` (replace `myusername` with your username, `mycommand` with the command to execute and adjust the niceness value as you like):

```
myusername ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/nice -n -20 sudo -u myusername mycommand
```

**Explanation:**
Allow the user `myusername` to execute the command `sudo /usr/bin/nice -n -20 sudo -u myusername mycommand` as root without entering a password. Since `sudo nice -n -20 mycommand` would execute `mycommand` as root we prepend `sudo -u myusername` to the command, that way `mycommand` is executed by `myusername`. This is a security measure to adhere the principle of least privilege.

### 2) Execute the command using sudo in the service script

Now we can execute this specific command without entering a password:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=sudo /usr/bin/nice -n -20 sudo -u myusername mycommand
```

#### Example: xcape

/etc/sudoers

```
myusername ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/nice -n -20 sudo -u myusername xcape -t 180 -e Caps_Lock=Escape
```

~/.config/systemd/user/xcape.service

```
[Unit]
Description=xcape: esc on caps lock
PartOf=graphical-session.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=sudo /usr/bin/nice -n -20 sudo -u myusername mycommand

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Start the service: `systemdctl --user start xcape`

---

<sup>1</sup> One could also write a helper executable and use the setuid bit, if sudo is not available.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Unit]
    Description=Colibri
    After=uart.service
    #After=network-online.target
    #Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
    Type=simple
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=60
    #ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 20 
    User=colibri
    Nice=-10
    StandardOutput=null
    StandardError=null
    SyslogIdentifier=Colibri
    # LogLevelMax=warning
    WorkingDirectory=/home/colibri/colibri/      
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/env python /home/colibri/colibri/main.py
    TimeoutStopSec=10
    #KillMode=process 

[Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Can you give some explanation?